# Generate dynamic time representation using DAX

Tags: powerbi

I am relatively new to PowerBI and struggling to accomplish the following task.
I have in total 3 Tables. 2 Tables are available and the 3rd is the outcome I am interested in.

[image]

Table 1 is a lookup table with yearly values for each option of a certain property.
Table 2 is a user input table containing the project list with a property that can be equal to one of the options in Table 1.

I am mostly interested in Mapping the projects with their yearly development based on one property. The outcome is represented in Table 3.
At the end of the day, I would like to plot the Sum across all projects against the year column (The 2 columns in red).
I hope someone can help here in finding the appropriate DAX logic. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can create relationship between table 1 & table 2 to represent the project no as column name in table 1, not code is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can bring the tables into a Power BI model, and from the modeling tab you can create relationships to accomplish this. Let me know if this is helpful.